# How to use then() and get the value in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have a span element which value is 2. I would like to check if the value is greater than 0, but after checked online and implemented every method, it did not work...

Here is the console when I log the $span

[image]

I understand that Cypress works asynchronously, so I use `.then()` to get the text of element. How can I get the value of 2 and do the follow if-else?

HTML

```
<div>
  <span class="badge ml-1 badge-primary">2</span>
</div>
```

```
   cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary").then(($span)=> {
     if($span.text().includes(0)) {
      doFunction1()
    } else {
      cy.get(xxxxx)
    }
 )}
```

Comment: What do you get when you write this `cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary").invoke('text').then((text) => {cy.log(text)})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it by chaining conversions methods to go from from `element` -> `text` -> `number`

```js
cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary")
  .invoke('text')                    // to text
  .then(text => +text)               // to number
  .then(value => {
    if(value > 0) { 
      doFunction1()
    } else {
      cy.get(xxxxx)
    }
  })
```

---

**Waiting for value `2`**

```js
cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary")
  .invoke('text')                    // to text
  .then(text => +text)               // to number
  .should('eq', 2)                   // wait for value 2
  .then(() => {
    doFunction1()                    // now doFunction
  })
```

Comment: I log the text, the value shows 0 instead of 2. And I click the invoke, the yielded is 0. Does it means cypress get the previous value, not the current one?

Comment: I guess that the way how I get the span value is in asynchronous, so when cypress runs, it will get the very first value which is 0.

Comment: Ok, but if you want to wait for it to be `2` then you don't need `if() else()` - it will always `doFunction1()`

Comment: I think you are re-querying, but you can just increase the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for is to check if content of a span is GRATER THAN 0. So it will require some additional apprach than using `includes`. For example you  may read a value as a variable and check if it is grater than 0:

```
 cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary").then(($span)=> {
     const value = $span.text(); // now you know what the value is
     if(value > 0) { // actual check if > 0. Beware, implicit coersion here! read more below.
      doFunction1()
    } else {
      cy.get(xxxxx)
    }
 )}
```

The `value` variable, however, is a string. My code works since JS would convert string to number automatically. Depending on your use-case, you might want to make sure it is a valid number and not some other string, which can't be converted to a number (like "2s").
For example, if the value is "2s", than the `value > 0` check would be falsy, which might result in a bug in your code.

```
 cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary").then(($span)=> {
     const value = Number.parseInt($span.text()); // now you know what the value is
     if(!Number.isNaN(value) && value > 0) { // value is now of type number, but it may be NaN! (yes, NaN is also a number)
      doFunction1()
    } else {
      cy.get(xxxxx)
    }
 )}
```

Comment: If I log "$span", it shows a jQuery object and the value I want in the attribute innerHTML. But, I can not get it if I console.log($span.innerHTML)

Comment: if it's a jQuery object, did you tired $span[0].innerHtml? Maybe it is a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the selector that you are using is unique, so that is shouldn't fetch an unintended value. Secondly you can wait with a custom timeout in case your webpage takes some time to populate the value and then apply your if-esle condition. Now instead of 4 seconds(cypress default timeout), the should command will re-try for 7 seconds to check that the element has the inner text value of 2.

```js
cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary", { timeout: 7000 }).should("have.text", "2")

cy.get(".badge.ml-1.badge-primary")
  .invoke(text)
  .then((num) => {
    if (+num > 0) {
      doFunction1()
    } else {
      cy.get(xxxxx)
    }
  })
```